# URL-Form-Encoded Request AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

Form-Encoded Request from AFNetworking I want to pass parameters through dictionary but i am having values in array like 
(
    2,
    6,
    9,
    12,
    15
)

This array length can change but i want to pass the @"tags[]" :@""( here i want to populate array)

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];


NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"user_id" : userId ,
                             @"token" :  userToken ,
                             @"tags[]" : @"9" ,

                            @"tags[]" : @"2" ,

                             @"tags[]" : @"5" ,

                             @"tags[]" : @"16"

                             };



[manager POST:@"http:example.com" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"user_id" : userId,
                               @"token" : userToken,
                                @"tags" : tagsArray};
```

?